# Concurrent sd_setimage call

Tags: swift

I'm using sd_setimage function to load imageviews in a collection view cell.
The problem is when i call sd_setimage twice, only the first image is set while the second is not. How can i call two sd_setimage functions concurrently and setting both images correctly?

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
      if indexPath.row == 0 {
        cell.likesImage.sd_setImage(with: urlString1Temp as URL!, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "imageLoading"))
        cell.likeUserPic.sd_setImage(with: userProfileUrl as URL!, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "imageLoading"))
    }
```

Any help is very much appreciated. :)

Comment: Did you try using the sd_setImage overload with the "completion" block?

Comment: Yes i've tried the sd_setImage with a completion block to load the second imageview but the same results i.e. second imageview not loaded.

Comment: and if you remove the first line with likesImage does the likeUserPic load correctly?

Comment: yes it does. both lines are confirm working with the right URL.